# Normalize column in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Is there a possibility a to normalize a column in Clickhouse?

I was trying to do it getting the column into array via groupArray and then using arrayMap with lambda function 
`arrayMap(x -> (x-minArray(c)) / (maxArray(c)-minArray(c), c)` to normalize the data in the array.

But it seem a little bit clunky, cause it should be a subquery that repeats the actual query and then JOIN this subquery to it.

So, is there a better solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... just try use standart aggregation function like this:

```
SELECT c, (c-min(c)) / (max(c)-min(c)) AS normalized_c FROM table GROUP BY c
```

Comment: It's invalid. `c` is not in `GROUP BY`